# Truncated password hash in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, hash, drupal, passwords, truncated

I'm in a Drupal 8 mysql database (part of a lab so not illegally) and the password hash seems to be truncated in the users_field_data database. I've never quite seen this, and any searches I can find don't seem to tell me anything. I'm not sure how Drupal would ever verify the password if it doesn't have the full hash?

The hash I'm getting back looks something like this:
$S$E6GCf39Fu376XcvVHzroZhuiOp3jRURyhDwOMzGfT22X3b..X4ed

I tried changing the column size from varchar 55 to varchar 100 and nothing happened. I'm retrieving the password hash using the following statement:

SELECT pass FROM users_field_data;

Is there something I'm missing that is preventing me from pulling the full hash?

Comment: It is not necessary to have the full hash. The server might compare only the same number of bytes as the stored hash from the freshly hashed password. Whether this is actually done is another question. I haven't looked into Drupal.

Comment: Yeah it's possible they could compare just part of the hash, but seems odd as that would decrease security if anything. I'm guessing due to the CTF/lab style of my environment that it's purposely some kind of misconfiguration (the column size was deliberately too small) but I'm wondering if it's just something I don't know about mysql/drupal.

Comment: Woops, I never asked my question! Is there anything i"m missing that is able to pull the full hash (some sort of query) or is this just an issue with storing too large of a value into too small of a column?

Comment: @user15262123 where are you seeing this output? Seems strange that it would be truncated like that

Comment: @lucasreta, It's from a paid lab environment and is on a SQL database for one of the machines. It is not a machine in production,  nor is it part of an exam of any sorts.

Comment: I understand, I'm just wondering where exactly are you seeing that string, how do you get that particular output? From executing the query in the MySQL CLI? Navigating the DB through some GUI? Output of some script?

Comment: through the MySQL CLI.